# Automatic shutdown after 2 hours on every boot

Tags: scripts, lubuntu, shutdown, startup

I am using both Ubuntu and Lubuntu 16.04 and this question is regarding both of them.

I want my computer to always shut down 2 hours after it was turned on, i tried to use [these instructions](https://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/05/schedule-tasks-to-automatically-shutdown-restart-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/) that I found to run a timed shutdown on startup but it does not work.

How can I do that?

Comment: Not enough information here on what did not work. Can you post the results of `cat /etc/crontab` ?

Comment: it was not a specific error, nothing happened and the Os was acting normal. could you please assist me with a straight forward - not to complex solution the the question in the op?

Answer (score 3):

**1.Edit sudoers (you must be root):**

```
gedit /etc/sudoers
```

At the end add following:

```
yourusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown
```

and save.

**2.Crete .sh script:**

```
gedit myscript.sh
```

add following there:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo shutdown -P +120 # shut down after 120 minutes
```

**3.run "startup applications" tool you just need write it in search box. And press Add button:**

[image: startup applications]

[image: Add]

Write there your .sh script name and path to it. Press add there too.